# Error while decrypting the encrypted content of the file

Tags: java, encryption

I am developing a program for Encryption and Decryption , the Encryption is working fine, but the Decryption is throwing error.
I am not able to find, What is the problem in that code??

```
key.txt
ssshhhhhhhhhhh!!!!

plaintext.txt
naddarbhatia.com





public class hello {

private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
private static byte[] key;

public static void setKey(String myKey)
{
    MessageDigest sha = null;
    try {
        key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
        sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secret)
{
    try
    {
        setKey(secret);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secret)
{
    try
    {
        setKey(secret);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) 
          throws IOException 
        {
          byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
          return new String(encoded, encoding);
        }




public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{


    String en_de_flag = args[0];

    String secretKey="";
    try {
        secretKey = readFile("/Users/amulbhatia/Documents/EclipseProjects/HelloProject/src/key.txt",StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        //System.out.println(secretKey);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String originalString="";
    String encryptedString="";

    try {
        originalString = readFile("/Users/amulbhatia/Documents/EclipseProjects/HelloProject/src/plaintext.txt",StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    if(en_de_flag.equals("0")) {

        encryptedString = hello.encrypt(originalString, secretKey) ;
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("encrypt.txt");
        out.println(encryptedString);
        System.out.println("Encrypted File Generated !! 'encrypt.txt' , Please check now");
        out.close();
    }

    if(en_de_flag.equals("1")) {

        String decryptedFileContent = readFile("/Users/amulbhatia/Documents/EclipseProjects/HelloProject/src/encrypt.txt",StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        System.out.println("decryptedFileContent:" + decryptedFileContent);
        System.out.println("Secret Key:" + secretKey);

        String decryptedString = hello.decrypt(decryptedFileContent, secretKey) ;
        //System.out.println("Read Encrypted File, Now Decrypting..");
        //System.out.println(decryptedString);
    }


}}


STACKTRACE

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input byte array has incorrect ending byte at 44
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:771)
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:535)
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:558)
    at hello.decrypt(hello.java:63)
    at hello.main(hello.java:12
```

8)

While executing the above code at command line with argument as '0' the encrypt.txt file will be generated with the encrypted content, and after that when I entered argument as '1' it reads the encrypted file 'encrypt.txt' and 'key.txt' and calls the decrypt function where the same function is getting failed, pl help

Comment: what do you mean when you say the "function is getting failed"?

Comment: i mean the function throws exceptions

Comment: if you say which exceptions are being thrown in the question and where on the stacktrace it might be easier for people to find the problem.

Comment: Please change your program to print the stacktrace, then add the stacktrace to the Question.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: stacktrace is added..

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html) for `Base64.Decoder.decode()`, `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown when the byte array passed as input is "not in valid Base64 scheme". You might want to check what you're giving to it and use a debugger.

Comment: I can't edit as there is currently one pending peer review but I feel your question could be improved if you replace "Error" in your title with "IllegalArgumentException" and add more tags to make it easier for people having this same issue to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is thrown by the Base64 decoder because your ciphertext ends with a line terminator, written by the `PrintWriter`.

Just `.trim()` your `decryptedFileContent` (which is actually the encryptedfilecontent...) to remove the line break.